# Парсинг, Не могу получить цену товара

Tags: python, парсер

Ищу блок с карточкой товара, но не могу взять цену. Есть еще один момент, не все цены в одинаковых тегах span.
Вот сайт https://www.zoohit.cz/shop/psi/granule/bosch
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def get_content(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find('div', {'data-zta': 'product-list-wrapper'}).find_all('div', {'data-zta': 'product-box-list'})

    products_page = []
    for item in items:
        products_page.append({
            # 'product_name': item.find('a', {'data-zta': 'product-link'}).get_text(strip=True),
            # 'product_code': item.get('data-shop-identifier'),
            'product_cost': item.find('div', class_='js-productList')
        })
    return products_page
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'product_cost': item.find(itemprop='price').get('content')
```

поменяйте свое, на это. вроде работает.

Comment: Работает, спасибо тебе друг)